# Using converter with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

so I'm new in using spring mvc , for the fist tutorial I followed the example of http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/ tutorial . So we have a datamodel called User and another datamodel userProfile , we have a relation between the user and userProfile , every user have one or many userProfile , here is the class

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable{
......

@JsonManagedReference
@NotEmpty
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "APP_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") }) 
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>(); 

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
```

So , to add a new user with userProfile we have to add a converter for userProfile

**RoleToUserProfileConverter.java**

```
@Component
public class RoleToUserProfileConverter implements Converter<Object, UserProfile>{

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleToUserProfileConverter.class);

@Autowired
UserProfileService userProfileService;

/**
 * Gets UserProfile by Id
 * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
 */
public UserProfile convert(Object element) {
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
    UserProfile profile= userProfileService.findById(id);
    logger.info("Profile : {}",profile);
    return profile;
}
```

}

The form works fine and I can add a new user without any errors , after that I created another relation , I added a new class Car.java in relation with User.java ,

**Car.java**

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
.........

@JsonManagedReference
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
private User user;

}
```

I added a converter for the user class

**StringToUser.java**

```
@Component
public class StringtoUser implements Converter<Object, User>{

@Autowired
UserService userService ;

@Override
public User convert(Object element) {
    if (element == null ) {
        return null;
    }
        Integer id = ((User)element).getId();
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        return user;
}
```

After adding this converter I get an error in user form and Car form works fine :

**Error :**

```
WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to required type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to type [@javax.validation.Valid com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] for value 'User [id=null, ssoId=c, password=c, firstName=c, lastName=c, email=c]'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I removed the User Converter , the user form works fine and in the car form I get an error :

**Error :**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

how can it be done please !!!!!!

Comment: https://github.com/alaa-bourouissi/SpringMVCHibernate Here is all classes

Comment: The reason you are receiving the first error is because one of the information required to be of type `User` is null -- thus the Null Pointer Exception. I believe it has to do with an id field being null.

Comment: So what you think about the solution ?

Comment: I just skimmed through your java files and discovered you never set the User ID. This could be causing your NPE -- since you're calling .getId() method.

Comment: the id is auto increment , so no need to add it ? what do you think ?

Comment: If that's the case, I do not know why it's returning a null value. According to your error:
`'User [id=null, ssoId=c, password=c, firstName=c, lastName=c, email=c]'`
the id is null and you're calling `User user = userService.findById(id);`
Perhaps check the id field in a simple Sys.out?

Comment: When I submit a new user in the second case ( removing the user converter ) .It works fine and all the new user are created with their own Id incremented normally